# How should I update indicies after an item was deleted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am working on the `contacts` module of my Google chrome extension. The user can add and delete contacts. Everything is done with JavaScript and jQuery.

**This question is more about the logic so don't be discouraged by the code.**

This is how a contact is added:

```
function addContact(name){
 var n = incContactNum();
 chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().setItem('contact'+n+'', name); 
 contacts[n] = name;
}
```

The total number of contact should be incremented, so we have `n` contacts now. Besides we update the contacts array.

So the SQLite item table looks like this:

```
 ------------------------
|  key          value    |
 ------------------------
| contactNum     3       |
 ------------------------
| contact1       Test1   |
 ------------------------
| contact2       Test2   |
 ------------------------
| contact3       Test3   |
 ------------------------
```

When a row is deleted, e.g. row 2 the table looks like this:

```
 ------------------------
|  key          value    |
 ------------------------
| contactNum     2       |
 ------------------------
| contact1       Test1   |
 ------------------------
| contact3       Test3   |
 ------------------------
```

Like you can see `contactNum` is decremented. We now have two items but the second has 3 as index but it should be changed from contact3 to contact2. You might realize the problem when you see my delete function:

```
function removeContact(value){
 contacts = new Array(getValue("contactNum"));
 for(i = 1; i <= parseInt(getValue("contactNum")); i++){
  if(getValue("contact"+i) == value){
   chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().deleteItem("contact"+i);
   decContactNum();
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

An item is deleted by value. So I search for the corresponding index to delete the row. Since the number of contacts is now 2, the index 3 is never reached.

My idea: the first removal works, so after that the indices should be rebuild. From the one that was deleted decrement all indices.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You might need to modify the background page code, to decrement the x in `contact'x'` for `x>i` where `i` is the item to be deleted.

Comment: Yes I know but how? here is my backgroundpage code http://jsfiddle.net/3jrv4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. First option is what I mentioned in the comment below your question.

- Modify the code in the background page to decrement every key that  follows the one that is to be deleted.

```
function removeContact(value){
    var len = getValue("contactNum");
    var found = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < len; i++){
        if(found==0 && getValue("contact"+i) == value){
            found=1;
        }
        if (found==1){
            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().setItem("contact"+i,getValue("contact"+(i+1)));
        }
     }
     decContactNum();
     chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().deleteItem("contact"+len);
}
```

- This method is fine only if the order doesnt much matter. Swap the record(the data part) to be deleted with the last record, and then remove the last record the way you done in the code posted.

```
function removeContact(value){
    var len = getValue("contactNum");
    for(i = 1; i <= len; i++){
        if(getValue("contact"+i) == value){
            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().setItem("contact"+i,getValue("contact"+len));
            break;
        }
     }
     decContactNum();
     chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().deleteItem("contact"+len);
}
```